# Cannot open file from oracle

Tags: .net, oracle, file-access, lob, utl-file

I am trying to select bytes from oracle database and convert them to image file. When I wrote the oracle procedure it stops in UTL_FILE.fopen and returns a ORA-29280 error. Oracle community says that this error is caused because OS level user may has no permission to write to a folder, or we should use upper_cases. But for suggestion 1, I tried to access the same folder using .Net and image file was created successfully, for suggestion 2 I tried using upper cases but I am still facing the same error. What could be the problem? Why I can create file from .Net but not from oracle? Below is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE BLOB_UPDATE (file_name in varchar) IS

    file_ref UTL_FILE.file_type;
    raw_max_size constant number := 32767;

 begin

   file_ref := UTL_FILE.fopen('C:\LOB', file_name, 'WB', raw_max_size);
   -- Here it stops working ! -- 
   ....
   utl_file.fclose(file_ref);

END BLOB_UPDATE;
```

Comment: Oracle is installed locally on your machine or you're using remote DB?

Comment: No @Kacper, it is not installed on my machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please execute on your DB:

```
create or replace directory DIR as 'C:\LOB'
grant read, write on directory DIR to your_user
```

And then access directory in your procedure by:

```
file_ref := UTL_FILE.fopen('DIR', file_name, 'WB', raw_max_size);
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what do you mean by your_user and where I have to add the code above, should it be before creating oracle procedure or inside? Sorry for my question but I am still a beginner in Oracle

Comment: @H.Al: From PL/SQL, you cannot access any random directory or file. You only have access to directories that you have declared (`CREATE DIRECTORY XXX AS ...`) and granted the necessary rights before using them. And you have to refer to them by the symbolic name (`XXX` in the above case). Otherwise, you get the ORA-29280 error.

Comment: @Kacper I discovered now what you mean by your_user and that your code should be implemented inside my procedure after begin but I don't know why it is returning  a PLS-00103 ora error, Am I missing something?

Comment: Okay @Codo thank you for your declaration it clarifies many things

Comment: @H.Al create and grant you execute only once. Then in procedure use last line in my post.